# how to display all the retrieved data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

using PHP & MYSQL on WordPress and Google Map API in order to retrieve data from MYSQL database and display markers with info windows on Google Map.

problem is that the map doesn't appear on the webpage, yet the SQL query is retrieving the required data.

where i have SQL query:

that retrieve data and display it in table

## example:

```
    {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8533166667, 35.5077833333),
    info:'BIS001',
    height: '48',
    site_name: Bissan',

}
,{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8533166667, 35.5077833333),
    info:'BIS002',
    height: '48',
    site_name: Bissan',

}
,{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8533166667, 35.5077833333),
    info:'BIS003',
    height: '48',
    site_name: Bissan',

}
```

this what must be displayed on the web page  the system display instead just the last value:

**Bissan    Fadi El Moussawi    gds     BIS003**

how to make the system or the query display all the required records?

## code:

```
<?php
        // code for submit button action
        global $wpdb, $site_name;
    //variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)



    if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
    {


       if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];

          }
          else { $site_name=""; }


        if(isset($_POST['owner_name'])) 
         {
          $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name']; 

         } 
         else { $owner_name=""; }

         if(isset($_POST['Company_name'])) 
         {
          $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];

         } 
         else { $company_name=""; }

        if(isset($_POST['Subcontractor_name'])) 
        { 
         $Subcontractor_name=$_POST['Subcontractor_name']; 

        }
        else { $Subcontractor_name="";}



 //   var_dump($site_name);

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = %s
    AND 
    o.ownerNAME = %s
    AND 
    x.companyNAME = %s
   ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
//echo $sql;

//    var_dump($_POST['site_name']);

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {



$obj->siteNAME;
$obj->ownerNAME;
$obj->companyNAME;
$obj->subcontractorNAME;
$obj->siteID;
$obj->equipmentTYPE;
$obj->latitude;
$obj->longitude;
$obj->height;
$obj->ownerCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY;

    } 

// table that will dsiplay the results based on the user's selection //
   echo "<table width='30%' ";

echo     "<tr>";
echo           "<td>Site Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Owner Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Company Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Subcontractor Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Site ID</td>";
echo           "<td>Equipment Type</td>";
echo           "<td> Lattitude</td>";
echo           "<td>Longitude </td>";
echo           "<td> Height</td>";
echo           "<td> Owner Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub company Name</td>";
echo   "</tr>";  
echo   "<tr>";        
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo  "</tr>";

echo  "<tr>";
echo     "<td>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text identifier (') right before 'Bissan' is always missing.
Try it with text identifier before and after the string.
Like that:

```
{
position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8533166667, 35.5077833333),
info:'BIS001',
height: '48',
site_name: 'Bissan',

}
,{
position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8533166667, 35.5077833333),
info:'BIS002',
height: '48',
site_name: 'Bissan',

}
,{
position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8533166667, 35.5077833333),
info:'BIS003',
height: '48',
site_name: 'Bissan',
}
```

Comment: your answer did not solve the problem i still get the last record and not all the records

Comment: Hmm, was worth a try.