# sql query doesn't retrieve all the records just retrieve the last record

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

using PHP & MYSQL on WordPress and Google Map API in order to retrieve data from MYSQL database and display markers with info windows on Google Map.

problem is that the map doesn't appear on the webpage, yet the SQL query is retrieving the required data.

where i have SQL query:

that retrieve data and display it in table

example  i have  3 records that must be displayed based on the user selection
but the query just display the last record not the 3 records

where is th error in the query :

## query:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = %s
    AND 
    o.ownerNAME = %s
    AND 
    x.companyNAME = %s
   ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
//echo $sql;

//    var_dump($_POST['site_name']);

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {



$obj->siteNAME;
$obj->ownerNAME;
$obj->companyNAME;
$obj->subcontractorNAME;
$obj->siteID;
$obj->equipmentTYPE;
$obj->latitude;
$obj->longitude;
$obj->height;
$obj->ownerCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY;

    } 

// table that will dsiplay the results based on the user's selection //
   echo "<table width='30%' ";

echo     "<tr>";
echo           "<td>Site Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Owner Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Company Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Subcontractor Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Site ID</td>";
echo           "<td>Equipment Type</td>";
echo           "<td> Lattitude</td>";
echo           "<td>Longitude </td>";
echo           "<td> Height</td>";
echo           "<td> Owner Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub company Name</td>";
echo   "</tr>";  
echo   "<tr>";        
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo  "</tr>";

echo  "<tr>";
echo     "<td>";

?>
```

Comment: After `foreach` is over, `$obj` stores last value.

Comment: this is a repost http://stackoverflow.com/q/42762972/1415724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your table rows inside the while loop and your title line before the loop and then you will see all the data and not just the last line

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME, i.equipmentTYPE, c.latitude
     , c.longitude, c.height , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT, x.companyNAME, y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME, y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
    LEFT JOIN owner_info o on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
    LEFT  JOIN company_info x on i.companyID = x.companyID
    LEFT JOIN subcontractor_info y on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c on i.siteID=c.siteID 
  where i.siteNAME = %s
    AND o.ownerNAME = %s
    AND x.companyNAME = %s
   ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

// table that will dsiplay the results based on the user's selection //
echo "<table width='30%' ";
echo     "<tr>";
echo           "<td>Site Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Owner Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Company Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Subcontractor Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Site ID</td>";
echo           "<td>Equipment Type</td>";
echo           "<td> Lattitude</td>";
echo           "<td>Longitude </td>";
echo           "<td> Height</td>";
echo           "<td> Owner Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub company Name</td>";
echo   "</tr>";  

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {
    echo   "<tr>";        
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
    echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";

} 

echo '</table>';   

?>
```

Comment: That's true @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- Same code, different question. OP had not realised this issue at that point I suppose

Comment: @RiggsFolly I s'pose.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yea... I was wrong. You can DUP this if you want I have copied my answer to the other question

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the code, you will see that the `foreach` loop keeps on assigning different property values to `$obj`.
But you didn't `echo` them out. So nothing will show up.
Then when the loop finishes, `$obj` has the property values of the last line of your table. And then you echoed them.

What you have to do is `echo` the table rows inside of your `foreach` loop. So as soon as it assigns values to `$obj`, you `echo` them.

After the loop, close out the table.

```
echo "<table width='30%'>";

echo     "<tr>";
echo           "<td>Site Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Owner Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Company Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Subcontractor Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Site ID</td>";
echo           "<td>Equipment Type</td>";
echo           "<td> Lattitude</td>";
echo           "<td>Longitude </td>";
echo           "<td> Height</td>";
echo           "<td> Owner Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub company Name</td>";
echo   "</tr>";

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {

$obj->siteNAME;
$obj->ownerNAME;
$obj->companyNAME;
$obj->subcontractorNAME;
$obj->siteID;
$obj->equipmentTYPE;
$obj->latitude;
$obj->longitude;
$obj->height;
$obj->ownerCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY;

echo   "<tr>";        
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo  "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```